# In C++ how do we call everything with a valid X(Args...) syntax that execute a function?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda, standards

In C++, there is a `Callable` concept as well as the `std::is_function` type traits. I was wondering how the standard calls `X`, when the exact expression

```
X(Args...)
```

is valid and corresponds to a call (excluding constructors and C macros). For now, I can think of the following that fit in that category:

- functions: `R(Args...)` (with optional `const`, `volatile`, `&`, `&&` qualifiers)
- function pointers: `R(*)(Args...)`
- function references: `R(&)(Args...)`
- functors (struct/class with overloaded `operator()`)
- lambda

My questions:

1. How does the standard call X? (eg.: not a `is_function` type because if `X` is a function pointer, `X(Args...)` is valid but `is_function` is false)
2. Did I forgot something in my list?

Comment: I'm think I'm missing something here. Because the answer is obvious: `X(...)`, where `...` is the argument list it wants to pass.

Comment: Ok, the thing is that I don't think that neither Callable nor std::is_function are refering to what I describe. For example if X is a function pointer, then X(Args...) is legal and corresponds to a call, even is std::is_function<X> is false.

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing because you ask "how the standard calls X". The meaning of the word call is a little ambiguous. I think what you mean is: what is the name of the class of entities X for which this expression is valid? I am not sure of the answer, but do you have an example of why the Callable concept is not what you want?

Comment: In principle there could be `std::is_callable<F>` and `std::is_callable<F(Args...)>` metafunctions that are more general than `std::is_function<F(Args...)>` .

Comment: Is the question "Why doesn't `std::is_function` include all callables"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems a bit confused. `std::is_function` only identifies [actual function types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function). It doesn't even include *pointers* to functions. The [FunctionObject concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FunctionObject) includes any object type that you can apply the function call operator to. This basically covers your list.

The [Callable concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable) includes FunctionObjects, but it includes other things. Callable adds member pointers (both data and functions) to the rest of the FunctionObject family.

The `INVOKE` feature of C++ is what gets applied to all Callable objects. `INVOKE` is not actually a function in C++; it's simply the standard's name for the algorithm for calling Callable objects with an argument list (C++17 corrects this absurd overseight, giving us `std::invoke`). Section 20.9.2 of the standard covers exactly how this algorithm is implemented.

The general gist is what you would expect. If the callable is a pointer-to-member-data, then you take the first argument, and apply that to the pointer-to-member-data (dereferencing that argument if it isn't a pointer). Same goes for pointer-to-member-functions, only you pass the rest of the arguments as parameters.

For FunctionObject types, you just use `()` to call it, passing it the arguments.